# Azure AD Directory Sync Issue

Tags: azure, active-directory

I started with an Office 365 account, then merged my user list with Azure Active Directory.  I have now setup a new (first time) domain controller, as I now wish to have apply some group policies to Office 365/Azure users.

I have a verified domain in Azure (we'll call it abcd.com), as well as a default abcd.onmicrosoft.com domain.  In my local active directory I have a domain of corp.abcd.com an added an additional domain of abcd.com. I have changed a few users to [username]@abcd.com, and put in their e-mail address in the "Mail" field in the general tab in AD.

In my Azure AD - all users have the UPN format of [username]@abcd.com.  I am trying to keep existing users and user names in AzureAD, and sync them with my local AD.

When I try to run the using AADSync, I get the following error (actual domain replaced with abcd.com below):

Unable to update this
 object because the following attributes associated with this object have values
 that may already be associated with another object in your local directory
 services: [ProxyAddresses SMTP:ABossio@abcd.com;UserPrincipalName  abossio@abcd.com;]. Correct or remove
 the duplicate values in your local directory. Please refer to  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2647098
 for more information on identifying objects with duplicate attribute values.

What is the best and easiest way that I can synchronize my Azure AD users with a local domain - for what it's worth, I have nothing important in my local AD or domain controller.

Answer (score 0):

In another forum, a person suggested using the powershell script here:
http://365lab.net/2014/04/18/office-365-migrate-from-cloud-identities-to-dirsync/

First I deleted all users (which was a key step), then I manually recreated them, and ran the script above.  I am now properly sync'd.